# Loading multiple splash screens / loading screens with timeout react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to load two consecutive splash screens before my signup page is loaded, I want each splash screen to be shown for a certain amount of time, I have tried with this code but it didn't work well for me.
this is my App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import TechInLifeSplashScreen from "./Screens/TechInLifeSplashScreen";
import NewLookSplashScreen from "./Screens/NewLookSplashScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./Screens/SignupScreen";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadingTIL: true,
      loadingNL: false,
      loadingWelcome: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const TILTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loadingTIL: false, loadingNL: true });
      this.showWelcome();
    }, 3000);
  }

  showWelcome = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loadingNL: false, loadingWelcome: true });
    }, 3000);
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loadingTIL) {
      return <TechInLifeSplashScreen></TechInLifeSplashScreen>;
    } else if (this.state.loadingNL) {
      return <NewLookSplashScreen></NewLookSplashScreen>;
    } else if (this.state.loadingWelcome)
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SignupScreen></SignupScreen>
        </View>
      );
    else return null;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Can anyone help me with this code in order to load my three screens in sequence?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what is not working?

Comment: It shows me a white screen and nothing else after.

Comment: Why are you setting state two times. Can it not be done simultaneously ? like; `setState({ loadingTIL: false, loadingNL: false })`. You could try checking with simple text component and output three flags to view if they are actually changing or not without using the if else statements.

Comment: I made those changes and nothing changed, same white screen or stuck in Downloading javascript bundle 100%

Comment: I have solved the problem by moving the if block that returns null to the bottom, now everything works fine, but there is something that I am worried about which is the timeouts are not cleared, any help with how and where to clear them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the timeouts by calling `clearTimeout()` for particular timeouts. But, for that, you should get the references to access within the component scope. You may use `this` keyword for that. For example, you may use `this.TILTimeout` instead of `const TILTimeout`.

Following is a better way to do what you want.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import TechInLifeSplashScreen from "./Screens/TechInLifeSplashScreen";
import NewLookSplashScreen from "./Screens/NewLookSplashScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./Screens/SignupScreen";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadingTIL: true,
      loadingNL: false,
      loadingWelcome: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showNewLook();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.TILTimeout);
    clearTimeout(this.NLTimeout);
  }

  showNewLook = () => {
    this.TILTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loadingTIL: false, loadingNL: true });
      this.showWelcome();
    }, 3000);
  }

  showWelcome = () => {
    this.NLTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loadingNL: false, loadingWelcome: true });
    }, 3000);
  };

  render() {
    if(this.state.loadingTIL) {
      return <TechInLifeSplashScreen/>
    }
    if(this.state.loadingNL) {
      return <NewLookSplashScreen/>
    }
    if(this.state.loadingWelcome) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SignupScreen/>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```